# Programmatically check names of required attendees in C#

Tags: c#, outlook-addin

I am writing a simple outlook addin and I need to get the required attendees to an appointment.

To doing that I use the following code:

```
...
Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment theCurrentAppointment = 
                                Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.AppointmentItem;
String attendees = appointment.RequiredAttendees;
/// attendees is empty if names are not checked
/// otherwise has the correct value
```

This code works well only if I use the check names functionality (CTRL+K) otherwise it returns an empty string.

It is possible to programmatically check names of required attendees (to an appointment) in C#?

Sorry but C# is not my programming language and I don't know if I use the right terms.

---

How to reproduce the error:

- I press new Appointment
- I add a required attendee
- I push a button calling my function

How to solve the problem (manually, not programmatically)

- I press new Appointment
- I add a required attendee
- I press CTRL + K
- I push a button calling my function

I need to know the value of RequiredAttendees before saving the appointment. So I can't save it and then check the value of RequiredAttendees.

Comment: Instead of downvoting try to explain why you should downvote it. It is not clear? It is an already solved question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to checking the attendees list, I think you first need to save the appointment item via:

AppointmentItem.Save();

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.save.aspx

After saving, get that appointment object again and run the code you need to obtain the Required Attendees (as below).

The string variable attendees will contain a semi-colon delimited string containing the names of each attendee.

From there, you could parse it via:

string[] names = attendees.Split(';');

which will return an array of the names of the attendees.

See the _[AppointmentItem.RequiredAttendees](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._appointmentitem.requiredattendees.aspx) property for more info.

Comment: I know, but if the attendees names are not checked the resulted string is empty. If I don't do  a CTRL+K (check names) before calling the RequiredAttendees parameter returns an empty string, after CTRL+K (check names) it returns the values separated by commas

Comment: I don't understand how you invoke the CTRL-K. Is it done when you are debugging, etc?

Comment: I add a name to the attendees manually. If I call my function (pressing a button) the RequiredAttendees string is empty. If then I manually type CTRL+K and I call again my function the RequiredAttendees is containg the right value. Basically if attendees are not underlined RequiredAttendees is empty. If they are underlined the RequiredAttendees value containes the right value.

Comment: Can you update the question to show where this CTRL K is happening? What is that CRTL K used for? Is that a trigger on your code? Or you are doing this from within Outlook?

Comment: I try to add some info on the question

Comment: Updated the answer. I believe you need to save first the appointment item and then from there, you would be able to obtain the names of the attendees.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the RequiredAttendees property, loop through all recipients in the Recipients collection and check that `Recipient.Type == olTo` (required).

Comment: Hello Dmitry. I tried and it works as the RequiredAttendees property. It means that if I don't check the names the Recipients doesn't contains the values inputed in the TO field.

Comment: The Recipients collection will be updated as soon as you tab out of the To edit box.